# Wordpress return incomplete post_content from get_post

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to render a page made by Elementor on my own custom page.
Using this code, I only get incomplete html string whose dom has no classname...

```
<?php
my_header();

$my_id = 1234;
$my_post = get_post($my_id);
$content = $my_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;

my_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Can you add an image as example please?

Comment: You can't use the `post_content` of a Elementor post because it's only a very raw version of the content. Elementor renders the html from the `_data_elementor` of `wp_postmeta`-table where the `post_id` matches.